# getting the location of the browser

Tags: browser, ip-geolocation

Is it possible for me to detect the geo-location of the place from where I'm browsing  through .net or through any means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need the database from this site (http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php) or... well from any other site who maintains an up to date database regarding this, and then just write some code to find a long in another list of longs ... (at least for IPv4)